# How can I pass a transition MUI prop to my child component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have one parent component with a button. when I click it, it opens a snackBar from MUI (child component). My teacher told me to add a transition effect to the onClick so when I show the snackbar, it has a slide transition.
I've tried to adjust MUI slide transition code from here [MUI transition](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-snackbar/) but I don't know how to pass the prop to the child component, I get an error in TransitionComponent={transition}. Any suggestion to make this working?

Parent component:

```
//NOTE: transition
type TransitionProps = Omit<SlideProps, 'direction'>;
const TransitionLeft = (props: TransitionProps) => <Slide {...props} direction="left" />


export const Messages = () => {

  const [msgStatus, setMsgStatus] = useState("");     
  
  //NOTE: transition
  const [transition, setTransition] = useState<React.ComponentType<TransitionProps> | undefined>(undefined);

  const handleClick = (Transition: React.ComponentType<TransitionProps>) => () => {
    setTransition(() => Transition);
    setMsgStatus('info');
  };

  return (
    <Stack>
       <Button
             onClick={handleClick(TransitionLeft)}
           >
             open info
           </Button>
           <InfoMessage
             open={msgStatus === 'info'}
             transition={transition}
             onClose={() => setMsgStatus('')}
           />
    </Stack>
  )
}
```

child component

```
interface InfoMessageProps {
  open: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
  transition: React.ElementType;
}

export const InfoMessage = ({ open, onClose, transition }: InfoMessageProps) => {

  const handleClose = (): void => {
    onClose();
  };

  return (
    <Snackbar
      open={open}
      autoHideDuration={4000}
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
      onClose={handleClose}
      TransitionComponent={transition} // here I have an error
    >
      <Alert
        sx={{
              width: '487px',
              height: '104px',
              paddingTop: '20px',
              paddingLeft: '20px',
              backgroundColor: '#FDFDFD',
        }}
        icon={false}
        action={(
          <IconButton
            aria-label="close"
            color="inherit"
            size="small"
          >
            <CloseIcon style={{ fontSize:'24px' }} />
          </IconButton>
        )}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <AlertTitle sx={{ paddingRight:'80px' }}>
          <Typography variant='headings.h4'>title</Typography>
        </AlertTitle>
        <Typography variant='captions.default'>Insert message here</Typography>
      </Alert>
    </Snackbar>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to pass the transition, once the `Snackbar` is mounted (`open={true}`) the transtion will work

if you want slide transition just define it:

```
import Slide, { SlideProps } from '@mui/material/Slide';

function SlideTransition(props: SlideProps) {
  return <Slide {...props} direction="up" />;
}
```

and then render pass it to `Snackbar` as `TransitionComponent`:

```
<Snackbar
   open={state.open}
   onClose={handleClose}
   TransitionComponent={SlideTransition}
   message="I love snacks"
   key={state.Transition.name}
/>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I've added it to my code and it's working fin now. Thanks for your quick response.